# Add Summary cost one by one with same foreign key at row sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem on sql server to get running summary of cost from foreign key in one time select data from table?

example : I have one table such as

```
 -----------------
| id | pid | Cost |
 -----------------
|  1 |  1  |   5  |
|  2 |  1  |   4  |
|  3 |  1  |   3  |
|  4 |  2  |   1  |
|  5 |  2  |   3  |
|  6 |  2  |   4  |
|  7 |  2  |   5  |
|  8 |  3  |   6  |
|  9 |  3  |   7  |
| 10 |  1  |   3  |
| 11 |  1  |   2  |
 -----------------
```

I want to get result as below

```
 ------------------------
| id | pid | cost | sum  |
 ------------------------
|  1 |  1  |   5  |   5  |
|  2 |  1  |   4  |   9  |
|  3 |  1  |   3  |  12  |
|  4 |  2  |   1  |   1  |
|  5 |  2  |   3  |   4  |
|  6 |  2  |   4  |   8  |
|  7 |  2  |   5  |  13  | 
|  8 |  3  |   6  |   6  |
|  9 |  3  |   7  |  13  |
| 10 |  1  |   3  |  15  |
| 11 |  1  |   2  |  17  |
 ------------------------
```

In above tables foreign key ('pid') Column has values 1 to 3 in different row numbers. I tried to add cost from each 'pid' field name. I havn't found any way to do this,

Can I do that? Can some one help me? am still newbie at sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a running total problem. You can use `SUM OVER()` for this.

```
CREATE TABLE Temp(
    id      INT,
    pid     INT,
    Cost    INT
)
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES
(1, 1, 5), (2, 1, 4), (3, 1, 3),
(4, 2, 1), (5, 2, 3), (6, 2, 4),
(7, 2, 5), (8, 3, 6), (9, 3, 7),
(10, 1, 3), (11, 1, 2);

SELECT
    *,
    [Sum] = SUM(Cost) OVER(PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY Id)
FROM Temp
ORDER BY id, pid

DROP TABLE TEMP
```